# UIViewControllers does not detects tap / touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am creating UIViewController programmatically. In its viewDidLoad, I am creating instance of custom UIView Component which has bunch of button and text filed. I set this view as viewControllers view.

But when I select any UIButton it does not fire any event  or  tapping inside UITextFiled does not bring  up keyboard either.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SomeView *sv = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.view = sv;
    //[self.view addSubView:sv];
    self.title = @"Something";
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this piece of code ? Even adding subivew does not work.
I added tapgesture to sv and It was getting detected but nothing else was getting selected on view.

I tried added buttons/textfiled to the viewcontrollers view directly. Then it works but not through customview component.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding a strong reference to the view, It might be getting deallocated.

```
@interface YOURCLASS ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeView *sv;
@end
```

And then Go back fro trying to add it as a subview.  See if that works.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sv = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubView:self.sv];
    self.title = @"Something";
}
```

Comment: So you see the buttons but tapping on them does nothing?

Comment: Yes, I see UIButtons, UITextFiled but I can not select them. If I directly add them to self.view instead of customview it works.

Comment: check what happen if you do: self.view.clipToBounds = YES, self.sv.clipToBounds = YES;

Maybe the size of the view is not the right one.